# SQL Join with multiple key with default non matching value

Tags: sql

I need help with a SQL join.

I have following data :

```
 Category Curr     Acct Sales
    A     USD      100  400
    A     INR      123  450
    A     CAD      322  475
    B     EUR      456  230
    B     USD      123  550
    B     GBP      125  900
    X     GBP      399 1000

T2   
Category Curr    Acct Customer
    A     USD       % C01
    A       %     123 C02
    A     CAD     322 C03
    B     USD       % C04
    B       %     456 C05
    B     CAD     555 C06
    B       %       % C07
    %       %       % C08
```

Expected Result of  T1  JOIN  T2  (Join KEYs are Category, Curr and Acct)

```
T1.Category T1.Curr T1.Acct T1.Sales T2.Customer   
     A         USD    100     400       C01   
     A         INR    123     450       C02   
     A         CAD    322     475       C03   
     B         EUR    456     230       C05   
     B         USD    123     550       C04   
     B         GBP    125     900       C07   
     X         GBP    399    1000       C08
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are really using.  I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: Hello,  I just need to join on Category, Curr, Acct as KEYs but if any of the key value are not matching then we need join on default value as '%' which is shown in the  T2 table :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using left joins and coalesce that should work on any platform.

```
SELECT T1.Category, T1.Curr, T1.Acct, T1.Sales,
  COALESCE(B.Customer, AWILD.Customer, BWild.Customer, BOTHWILD.Customer, 'NO CUSTOMER FOUND') AS Customer
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 AS B ON T1.Category = B.Category
                 AND T1.Curr = B.Curr 
                 AND T1.Acct = B.Acct
LEFT JOIN T2 AS AWILD ON T1.Category = AWILD.Category 
                     AND T1.Curr = AWILD.Curr 
                     AND AWILDB.Acct = '%'
LEFT JOIN T2 AS CWILD ON T1.Category = CWILD.Category
                     AND CWILD.Curr = '%' 
                     AND T1.Acct = CWILDB.Acct
LEFT JOIN T2 AS BOTHWILD ON T1.Category = BOTHWILD.Category 
                        AND BOTHWILD.Curr = '%' 
                        AND BOTHWILD.Acct = '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `%` is a wildcard, then one method uses

```
select t.*,
       (select 
        from t2
        where (t2.category = t.category or t2.category = '%') and
              (t2.curr = t.curr or t2.curr = '%') and
              (t2.acct = t.acct or t2.acct = '%')
        order by ((case when t2.category = '%' then 1 else 0 end) +
                  (case when t2.curr = '%' then 1 else 0 end) +
                  (case when t2.acct = '%' then 1 else 0 end) +
                 ) desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as customer
from t ;
```

Note:  `fetch first 1 row only` is ANSI SQL.  It might be spelled `limit` or `select top 1` in some databases.

Comment: Thanks.. buts seems its not working as in my actual script I have multiple columns in the inner table (unlike 1 in the example) also I have 5 diffenet table already joined on my main table and I also have Group by clause.  This is bit difficult to implement .... Can you please let me know how I can achive it in the Join logic itself ?

Comment: @kirtihaval . . . You should ask *another* question with appropriate data.  Changing a question after it has been answered is rude, because it can invalidate answers that lead to downvotes on people who put in effort to try to help you.

Comment: Sorry Gordon.. I dont intend to insult you and truly appreciate your help... I just want to say that how I can achive above in the Join statements itself so that it will be less overhead...